# Yocto recipe python whl package

Tags: python, tensorflow, yocto, python-wheel, recipe

I am writing a custom `yocto recipe` that should install a python package from a `.whl` file.

I tried it using a recipe that contains:

```
inherit pypi setuptools
PYPI_SRC_URI="http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi-zero/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/output-artifacts/tensorflow-1.5.0rc1-cp27-none-any.whl“
```

But it does not work that way, it states, that a `setup.py` file is missing and when trying to write a custom `do_compile` task that runs `pip install <PATH-TO-WHL>` it says, that pip is an unkown command.

When installing `.whl` files directly onto the target system one would type the following:

```
pip install <path-to-whl-file>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

.whl package is just a .zip file with python sources, and precompiled binaries for certain platform.

So, you can do something like this:

```
COMPATIBLE_HOST = "i686.*-mingw.*"                                                                  

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/9d/7a8cad803ef73f47134ae5c3804e20b54149ce62a7d1337204f3cf2d1fa1/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl;downloadfilename=MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.zip;subdir=${BP}"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "a948c70a1241389d7120db90d69079ca"                                                
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "6dd73240d2af64df90aa7c4e7481e23825ea70af4b4922f8ede5b9e35f78a3b1"             

inherit nativesdk python3-dir                                                                       

LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"                                                                            

PV = "1.1.1"                                                                                        
PN = "nativesdk-python3-markupsafe"                                                                 

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file:///${S}/MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info/LICENSE.rst;md5=ffeffa59c90c9c4a033c7574f8f3fb75"

do_unpack[depends] += "unzip-native:do_populate_sysroot"                                            

PROVIDES += "nativesdk-python3-markupsafe"                                                          
DEPENDS += "nativesdk-python3"                                                                      

FILES_${PN} += "\                                                                                   
    ${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/* \                                                       
"                                                                                                   

do_install() {                                                                                      
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info                 
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/markupsafe                                 

    install -m 644 ${S}/markupsafe/* ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/markupsafe/          
    install -m 644 ${S}/MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info/* ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info/
}
```

I haven't tested it, yet, but it already forms proper nativesdk package.
Note **downloadfilename=** parameter to the SRC_URI - without it, .whl file would not be extracted.

Answer (score 2):

Basing on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694762/5422708 answer I would like to share working recipe for engineering_notation 0.6.0 module which also provides only .whl package:

```
SUMMARY = "To easily work with human-readable engineering notation."
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/slightlynybbled/engineering_notation"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/c4/4712b8020b8a3ada129581be891e2dbbd6a4cf54195ea2b80f89bbc51756/engineering_notation-${PV}-py3-none-any.whl;downloadfilename=engineering_notation-${PV}-py3-none-any.zip;subdir=${BP}"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "5684efec41bc0738bb1fe625a71ffaf7"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "1ea1e450d575b4804723d0711b0609d2711dffac2f4b5548ee632c16a636d9f6"

inherit python3-dir

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file:///${S}/engineering_notation-${PV}.dist-info/METADATA;md5=5a9ae92d9fbf02bbcd5e4e94e6356cd3"

do_unpack[depends] += "unzip-native:do_populate_sysroot"

DEPENDS += "python3"

FILES:${PN} += "\
    ${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/engineering_notation \
    ${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/engineering_notation-${PV}.dist-info \
"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/engineering_notation
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/engineering_notation-${PV}.dist-info

    install -m 644 ${S}/engineering_notation/* ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/engineering_notation/
    install -m 644 ${S}/engineering_notation-${PV}.dist-info/* ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/engineering_notation-${PV}.dist-info/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my bbclass based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/73474261/2332068 by @b1czu

Maybe it needs help to work with `-native` or other suffix or prefix packages, I've only used it so far on one package :-)

```
# python3-whl.bbclass makes it simple to build a bitbake package 
# from python whl-only packages where no source package is available,
# such as: https://pypi.org/project/jwt/#files
#
# Below is an example file python3-jwt_1.3.1.bb
#
#SUMMARY = "python-jwt is a JSON Web Token (JWT) implementation in Python developed by Gehirn Inc."
#HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/GehirnInc/python-jwt"
#AUTHOR = " Kohei YOSHIDA <kohei.yoshida@gehirn.co.jp>"
#LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
#LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${S}/${WHL_BP}.dist-info/LICENSE;md5=54830c88a42666c6835a0f834f93a521"
#
#SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/66/1e792aef36645b96271b4d27c2a8cc9fc7bbbaf06277a849b9e1a6360e6a/${WHL_BP}-py3-none-any.whl;downloadfilename=${BP}.zip;subdir=${BP}"
#SRC_URI[md5sum] = "13af211933474ad6b2a5a4199d9b3a05"
#SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "61c9170f92e736b530655e75374681d4fcca9cfa8763ab42be57353b2b203494"
#
#inherit python3-whl

inherit python3-dir 

WHL_BPN="${@ d.getVar('BPN').replace(d.getVar('PYTHON_PN')+'-', '', 1)}"
WHL_BP="${@ d.getVar('BP').replace(d.getVar('PYTHON_PN')+'-', '', 1)}"
WHL_PN="${@ d.getVar('PN').replace(d.getVar('PYTHON_PN')+'-', '', 1)}"

do_unpack[depends] += "unzip-native:do_populate_sysroot"

DEPENDS += "python3"

FILES:${PN} += "\
    ${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/${WHL_BPN} \
    ${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/${WHL_BP}.dist-info \
"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/${WHL_BPN}
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/${WHL_BP}.dist-info

    install -m 644 ${S}/${WHL_BPN}/* ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/${WHL_BPN}/
    install -m 644 ${S}/${WHL_BP}.dist-info/* ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/${WHL_BP}.dist-info/
}
```